# Shell script for how to remove multiple occurences of words except the first one

Tags: duplicates

I have an file with the following:

H200:hostname1,hostname2,hostname3

H400:hostname4,hostname1,hostname5

H500:hostname2,hostname6,hostname4,hostname7

H700:hostname8,hostname5,hostname2,hostname7

I need to remove duplicate hostnames from the whole file and the output should look like this, where each line contains unique hostnames:

H200:hostname1,hostname2,hostname3

H400:hostname4,hostname5

H500:hostname6,hostname7

H700:hostname8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way in perl.

```
BEGIN{
  %hosts=();  # keep track of all hostnames
  %labels=(); # associate hostname with label
}
chomp;

# $label = H200, $hosts = hostname1,hostname2,hostname3
($label,$hosts) = split(/:/);

# for every hostname
foreach my $h (split(/,/,$hosts)) {

  # if we haven't see it yet, associate it with label and mark as seen.
  if(!defined $hosts{$h}){
    push(@{$labels{$label}}, $h);
    $hosts{$h} = 1;
  }
}
END{
  # output each label's hostname list
  foreach my $label (sort keys %labels){
    print "$label:" . join(",", @{$labels{$label}}) . "\n";
  }
}
```

You could save that to a file named `unique` and then run:

```
perl -n unique input_file

H200:hostname1,hostname2,hostname3
H400:hostname4,hostname5
H500:hostname6,hostname7
H700:hostname8
```

Comment: Thanks JRD for the detailed answer, that's very helpful because that's exactly what I was looking for!!